# How to get this text value out of the NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsarray

I have an array that when I output the NSlog as follows

```
 NSLog(@"%s entered with variants: %@ and SelectedVariants = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [_valueLabels objectAtIndex:0], _selectedVariantValue);
```

gives me the following output

```
2017-11-24 10:09:54.971304+0800 NWMPos[547:109817] -[ShopifyProductCardView addButtonTapped:] entered with variants: <UILabel: 0x1040e5330; frame = (0 0; 33.6667 17); text = 'small'; alpha = 0.87; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c4645c10>; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x1c0298d30>> and SelectedVariants = (null)
```

I need to get to the text ="small" and get small into an NSString, there must be some method to do this how do I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a UILabel in the NSArray so I simply assigned the Array context to the UILabel and read its text properly as follows and it all works

```
UILabel *jongel = [_valueLabels objectAtIndex:0];
UILabel *jongel2 = [_valueLabels objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *pelleplutt = jongel.text;
NSString *pelleplutt2 = jongel2.text;
```